# The skype client ， Why can't I login successfully?

Tags: authentication, skype

I want to call the interface of skype in my program，Implement the function of sending messages to friends, but the login is not successful，I followed Microsoft's operation documentation step by step, and I did not receive a prompt to log in successfully, nor did I receive any errors. The following is the address of the Microsoft document I refer to ： 
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/skype-sdk/websdk/docs/getapientrysignin

Below is a screenshot of my code：

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Skype Web SDK app</title>

</head>
<body>
<iframe id="xFrame" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script src="https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.15/SkypeBootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

    Skype.initialize({ apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255' }, api => {
        var app = new api.application;
        app.signInManager.signIn ({
            username: 'yidian99880@163.com',
            password: 'password'
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("signed in as", app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
        }, err => {
            console.log("cannot sign in", err);
        });
    }, err => {
        console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the console output after I run：

[image]

I configured nginx locally on my computer, modified the host file, and added the domain name in it "test.my-skype.com"

The apikey in the code is provided in the Microsoft documentation, I can't find the entrance to apply for apikey

If you can tell me why I can't log in to skype then it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add code as text, not image.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you very much for replying, I have replaced the screenshot with the code as you said

Comment: When I open test.my-skype.com using firefox browser, I get the error message "No strings exist for this error type", but I still don't understand what to do